# Why isn't my Binary2Hex code working?

Tags: java, binary, hex

I cant seem to find the problem in my code. It ends up with compile errors.It says the method Binary2Hex will recurse infinitely. I asked my TA and he said I was inputting a string?I don't understand

```
package binary2hex;

public class Binary2Hex {
public static String binary2Hex(String binary){
int pos = binary.length();
    String hex = "";
    while(pos>=0){
        int posMinus4 = pos-4;
        if(posMinus4<0)
            posMinus4 = 0;
        String last4Bits = binary.substring(posMinus4, pos);
        while(last4Bits.length()<4)
            last4Bits = "0" + last4Bits;
        switch(last4Bits){
            case"0000": hex = "0" + hex; break;
            case"0001": hex = "1" + hex; break;
            case"0010": hex = "2" + hex; break;
            case"0011": hex = "3" + hex; break;
            case"0100": hex = "4" + hex; break; 
            case"0101": hex = "5" + hex; break;
            case"0110": hex = "6" + hex; break;
            case"0111": hex = "7" + hex; break;
            case"1000": hex = "8" + hex; break;
            case"1001": hex = "9" + hex; break;
            case"1010": hex = "A" + hex; break;
            case"1011": hex = "B" + hex; break;
            case"1100": hex = "C" + hex; break;
            case"1101": hex = "D" + hex; break;
            case"1110": hex = "E" + hex; break;
            case"1111": hex = "F" + hex; break;    
        }
        pos -= 4;
    }
    return binary2Hex("1010");
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println( binary2Hex("1010101010111010"));

}

}
```

Comment: Please provide the compiler errors in your question.

Comment: Well, to start with, you've got some infinite recursion going on there. So that might be something you need to investigate.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
 at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1969)
 at binary2hex.Binary2Hex.binary2Hex(Binary2Hex.java:11)
 at binary2hex.Binary2Hex.binary2Hex(Binary2Hex.java:34)

Comment: Ah yes I see the infinite recursion. The error at line 34 repeats infinitely

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you shouldn't be doing recursion since you are solving the problem in a while loop.  You should just return hex.  You got the right code there for the most part.  Also, another hint is you should not process a string if its length is 0.

Comment: Right I had it return hex yet it still recurses infinitely.How would I fix the length problem?

Comment: it should literally end with: "return hex;".  So there is no way for it to recurse.  Length problem easily solved with while(pos>0) instead of while(pos>=0)

Comment: Ah I see, Thank you my friend!